# Is there any way a website can show it hasn't been "hijacked" by the authorities?

Tags: webserver, legal, security-theater

I heard about warrant canaries and thought the idea was interesting. My understanding of what they are is a website or online service publishes a statement periodically that they have not been served a warrant. This way even with a gag order, the act of not publishing something is not infringing it. I hear [warrant canaries don't actually work](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/268/is-there-any-legal-theory-behind-warrant-canaries) as a judge would likely find not publishing something to signal a warrant has been served would be in violation of a gag order.

My question is, is there an alternative to a warrant canary that would serve the same purpose (but actually work), that an online set or web service etc. has been ordered to change their behaviour by the government/police/rebels etc.? I'd imagine something Tor or P2P related could be used to spread the message "hey, we were forced to hand over user information".

Correct me if any of the above information is wrong; I'm not well versed in law, but do find this idea interesting.

Comment: Any communication provably originating from the gagged organization is easier to trust, but is more easily subject to legal repercussions. Anonymous communication is difficult to trust, but has less risk of successful prosecution. I believe you are looking for inductive evidence to increase credibility of an anonymous claim.

Comment: @AustinHartzheim yea, like an anonymous message that could only be decrypted with the gauged party's public key...or something like that. (not sure if legally it would be enough "evidence against them" if the authorities could decrypt the message with their public key, that would show they have violated the gag order).

Comment: IMO this belongs on http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure this is an InfoSec question. This seems a pure legal question.

Comment: But you are asking for something that would be a legal alternative, not a technical one. The barrier is the law, not technology. That's why it's not an InfoSec question.

Comment: @schroeder "But you are asking for something that would be a legal alternative, not a technical one" could you explain what you mean by this? Being legal and technology are not mutually exclusive, and it goes without saying I'm not looking for illegal advice.

Comment: @schroeder I'm not sure if I should delete this question because it's closed or leave it here because it received 4 upvotes?

Comment: @Celeritas I edited out the comments in your question having to do with a response to closure (those comments should be comments). The edit will bring the question back up to the top of the queue. We can see what the community thinks again.

Comment: As for your comment from November, yes, a legal remedy and a technical remedy are exclusive from each other because of the intent. A technical answer is a warrant canary, but you reject that on legal grounds. You are specifically asking for a solution (technical or not) that satisfies legal requirements or restrictions. As such, this is a purely legal question.